# JQ: Modify object that is the result of a filter while keeping the original structure

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have the following JSON

### Original Data

```json
{
  "myValues": [
    {
      "filterableValue": "x",
      "something": "else"
    },
    {
      "filterableValue": "y",
      "another key": "another value"
    },
    {
      "filterableValue": "z"
    }
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Using JQ I want to add a key value pair to the first (or all) entries in the `myValues` array, that have the `filterableValue=="y"`. The position/index of these entries inside the `myValues` array is arbitrary.

### Expected Output

The result should have the same structure (still contain both `foo` and `myValues`) but have a modified entry where `filterableValue=="y"`.

```json
{
  "myValues": [
    {
      "filterableValue": "x",
      "something": "else"
    },
    {
      "filterableValue": "y",
      "another key": "another value",
      "this": "has been added" // <-- this is the only thing that changed
    },
    {
      "filterableValue": "z"
    }
  ],
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

### What I tried and why it failed

So far I managed to filter the respective array entry and set the value on the filtered output but didn't manage to keep the original structure AND modifiy a filtered entry.
My JQ that adds the `"this":"has been added"` pair but does *not* contain the original structure is:

`.myValues|map(select(.filterableValue=="y"))[0]|.this="has been added"`
[jqplay mwe](https://jqplay.org/s/M-030I0lr0)

### Question

How can I modify a filtered entry as above *and* contain the original structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the whole selector on the LHS within parentheses:

```
(.myValues[] | select(.filterableValue == "y")).this = "has been added"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ApdfbDXDU7)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's cleanup

```
.myValues | map(select(.filterableValue=="y"))[0]
```

It's better written as

```
.myValues[] | select(.filterableValue=="y")
```

Not only is it shorter, it handles the case where there are 0 or 2+ matches better.

---

Then, you just need to change `... |` to `( ... ) |=`.

```
( .myValues[] | select(.filterableValue=="y") ) |= ( .this = "has been added" )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/DA2V5Dz8bu)